# ol tag in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple ol list in a div:

```
<div class="one">Title<hr width="200px">
<ol>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Divs CSS:

```
div.one {
float:left;
width:250px;
height:525px;
background-color:#e0e0e0;
font-size:30px;
margin:2px;
color:#6d6e71;
}
```

On FF and IE the numbers are created where the text (center alignment inherited) starts but on Chrome numbers are created where the div starts. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
div.one ol {list-style-position:inside; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yzyXE/